# Is it possible to change function runtime scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am working on a JavaScript library while I need to load different modules accordingly, I use the callback to load different scripts:

Just add the `main` script in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
(function () {
    var actionForT2 = function (fun) {
        fun && fun.apply(this);
    }
    var loadCallback = function (name, obj) {
        if (name == "t2") {
            actionForT2(obj);
        }
    }
    window.__jsload = loadCallback;
    var loadJs = function (js) {
        var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("src", js);
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    loadJs("js/t2.js");
})();
```

t2.js:

```
__jsload('t2', function () {
    console.info("t2 loaded");
    console.info(loadJs);
})
```

Now the `t2.js` will be loaded as expected. And I got the output:

```
t2 loaded
ReferenceError: loadJs is not defined
```

That's to say, the `loadJs` function is not accessed for the function defined in `t2.js`, then  I wonder if I can change the Runtime context of the loaded function, for example, when the loaded function is being called:

```
fun && fun.apply(this);
```

Is it possible to  make the call of `fun` under the context of current anonymous function, then all the defined variables, functions like the `loadJs` and etc can be accessed by `fun` without export them to the `window`?

---

Why I am interested in this kinds of solution is that I found google map use the callback, for example, when using google map v3, the following script will be loaded to the page:

```
https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/3/main.js
```

Then another module `map` will  be  loaded:

```
https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/3/{map}.js
```

While when deep in to the codes, I found that the `{map}.js` can access the variables defined in the `main.js`. But I can not find the how the magic happen.

Comment: `loadjs` only exists in scope, of the function, so you can either attach `loadjs` to a global object, like window

Comment: You should look at how this module loading functionality is achieved through [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). Or better yet, don't reinvent the wheel and just use require.js if possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change function runtime scope…I wonder if I can change the Runtime context of the loaded function, for example, when the loaded function is being called

No. Javascript is lexically scoped, so scope is entirely dependent on where functions are created in the code, not where they called from or how they are called

```
> fun && fun.apply(this);
```

That will only set one parameter of the function's execution context, its *this* parameter.

There is general confusion about the term *context*. In ECMA-262 (the standard for the language underpinning javascript) *context* is used exclusively in [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10), which is the [entire environment](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) inside a function and includes its *this* parameter.

The *call* and *apply* methods allow you to specify the value of a function's *this*, that's it, they have no other effect on the execution context (which is why *this* should never be called "context"). They do not have any effect on [identifier resolution](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1), which proceeds based on scope regardless of the value of *this* or where a function has been called from.

You might find the following article interseting: [*Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and scope chains*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc).

Comment: "fun.apply(obj) only set the `this` in side the function rather than the context" I never realize that. Thanks. Could you spare some time to check my update about why I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it global. Since you already have `window.__jsload` you could attach it there.

```
__jsload.loadJs = loadJs;

 // // access like this  :
 // console.info(__jsload.loadJS);
```

Or you could pass it to your callback when you call it from `__jsload`.

```
__jsload('t2', function (loadJs) {
   console.info("t2 loaded");
   console.info(loadJs);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, I never thought that, however it seems that only the `loadJs` is exported while the other variables,functions should be exported which is not sure.